# Condition code for Display custom content Only Homepage

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I was used below condition of Custom Box Content Display **Only for HomePage** in OpenCart 1.5.6. & this is working fine.

I was used this in `header.tpl` file.

```
<?php if (!isset($this->request->get['route']) || $this->request->get['route'] == 'common/home') {?>
    /////////////////////////
    /                       /
    /                       /
    /                       /
    /      Box Content      /
    /                       /
    /                       /
    /                       /
    /                       /
    /////////////////////////
<?php } ?>
```

**but, this is not working in OpenCart 2.0.**

How can the same thing be achieved in Opencart 2.0?

Comment: `echo $this->request->get['route']` and check for this printed value?

Comment: @mudasobwa It is not working. will any other solution possible? any example? Thanks.

Comment: **What** is not working? Did you printed out what I suggested? If yes, please share the output.

Comment: In OC2.0 you can no longer access `$this` and the objects from registry. To access them You'd need to add `$this->request->get['route']` to the array `$data` in controller and then use it in your template... I.e. `$data['route'] = $this->request->get['route'];` and then in template `<?php if ($route == 'common/home') { ?>`.

Comment: @shadyyx Your example is working fine. Thanks. & also, if, When, will all pages run this code & Only not run in homepage. So, how can is it possible in template? Thanks again.

Comment: @shadyyx Your example is Working fine in `www.mysite.com/index.php?route=common/home` but, Not working in `www.mysite.com` How can i solved this.

Comment: Use your brain? Or let the others solve everything for you. But I got it, I see where the problem is... Your pity. Here's how: `if (empty($route) || $route == 'common/home') { ... }`.

Comment: @shadyyx Finally solved our issue, I have add in controller `if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
   $data ['route'] = $this->request->get['route'];
  }` and then in template `<?php if (empty($route) || $route == 'common/home') {?>....<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found Perfect Solution. This is perfect work .

catalog/controller/common/header.php

add

```
if (!isset($this->request->get['route']) || $this->request->get['route'] == 'common/home'){
$data['ishome']=1;
}
```

then in your header.tpl

```
<?php if (isset($ishome)) {?>
Our Box Content
<?php } ?>
```